# Check if a cell is a valid standalone module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I’d like to be able to export the contents of some cells programmatically, but before doing so I’d like to check if the cell would run as a standalone python module/file.

Is there a way of quickly executing a cell via the API in a blank/fresh context to check if it would run by itself?

The manual version of this process for reference is to copy the contents of a cell into a new python file, then run it with python newfile.py and eliminate the NameErrors one by one.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to mess with the `globals()` object. That's where all top-level names are stored. You might be able to do something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
# top of code, to get clean globals
from copy import copy
original_globals = copy(globals())
del original_globals["copy"]

... # misc code

# now you want to check if it would work standalone, so set globals to original state
new_globals = copy(globals())
for name in new_globals:
    if name not in original_globals:
        del globals()[name]

... # do something standalone


# reset global state
for name, value in new_globals.items():
    globals()[name] = value
```

Not foolproof by any means (e.g. if you redefine a global like `sum`, but that's a bad idea generally anyway), but it should catch most what you're looking for. I would also look into implementing this feature as a context manager, so you could make it as simple as:

```
with restore_initial_global_state():
    ... # do something standalone
```